# Controll over the default Cache-Control: no-cache, private Nginx/php-fpm7.4 installation via Laravel Forge service

Tags: nginx, cache-control, ubuntu-20.04

Is there any way of changing the default of the `Cache-Control` header that is currently set to `no-cache, private` on all `html` type files?

I have tried changing this behavior via `nginx.conf` as well as via Forge panel, but nothing seems to work for me.

All other files are cached as they supposed to except the actual `html`

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/www.example.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;
    server_tokens off;
    root /home/forge/www.example.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/824182/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/824182/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;
    
    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    if_modified_since off;
    etag off;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload' always;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/www.example.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $query_string/index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    
    # browser caching of static assets
    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|json|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|woff|ttf|otf|svg|woff2|eot)$ {   
        expires 30d;                                                                                            
        access_log off;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2592000";
    } 

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/www.example.com/after/*;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following configuration?

```
map $uri $cache_control {
    ~\.html$  "public, max-age=2592000";
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        add_header Cache-Control $cache_control;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $query_string/index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_hide_header Cache-Control;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: All it did is added additional `public, max-age=2592000` to the existing `cache-control`, so now it looks as `no-cache, private, public, max-age=2592000`

Comment: Are you trying to change the `Cache-Control` header returned from your upstream?

Comment: correct, I do not need the default behavior, I need to be able to cache it for as long as I need

Comment: @AlexB Add the `fastcgi_hide_header Cache-Control;` directive to your FastCGI `location` block, see the updated answer.

Comment: trying it now will report back in a minute, also I have changed `~\.html$` to `~\.*$` as I do not particularly serve pages with `.html`

Comment: @AlexB Then I think it would be better to rely on `Content-Type` upstream header instead of `$uri` variable.

Comment: It did work and removed the unnecessary staff from the cache-control header as intended, yet it does not seem to me that the page is cached as I still see the service-worker in transfer instead of cached.

Comment: Not sure how to correctly change `$uri` variable to the `Content-Type` in the upsteam without messing it all up?

Comment: @AlexB Maybe I misunderstood your question, do you want to change nginx caching behavior?

Comment: You understood it correctly, I do need to change the behavior that nginx comes with out of the box so that I can cache all my static files as well as page content in the client browser for a period of 30 days

Comment: @AlexB Sorry, don't know how to help further.